# Иноязычные наименования

Tags: заимствования, переводы

Интересна стала одна тема, связанная с иноязычными названиями.

Как известно, сейчас в Российскую Федерацию — да и вообще в любую страну — привозят самые разнообразные продукты питания и разные жизненно необходимые вещи — например, шампуни, гели, мыло и многое-многое другое.

Это не суть вопроса. К примеру, есть шампунь «Schwarzkopf». Немного зная немецкий язык, Вы можете перевести это слово (скорее это словосочетание) как «Черная голова». Слово «Schwarz» я, несомненно, узнал сразу же, когда начал учить немецкий язык. А вот о слове «Kopf» я впервые услышал, когда читал о такой дивизии SS, как «Totenkopf», что с немецкого дословно обозначает «Мёртвая голова».

«И что Вас заинтересовало?» — скорее всего, подумаете вы.

Каждое ли иноязычное наименование можно перевести с языка-оригинала?

Comment: Можно,  не  нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что только в России в последние 10 лет уже перестали утруждаться переводить на русский язык подкатегорию товара. Например, по телевизору звучит: какой-нибудь "Орифлейм бьюти лайн", а должно быть: "Орифлейм - красивая линия" (или "линия красоты"). "Красивая линия" - это не торговая марка и должно быть переведено на русский язык. Ровно так же, как оно переводится на все остальные языки мира, где "Орифлейм" хочет иметь позицию на местном рынке.

Comment: Самое смешное или печальное не только то, что в рекламе иностранных продуктов ТОЛЬКО в России не переводят не только названия, но и подкатегории, и рекламные лозунги пишутся и звучат с экрана на чистом английском языке (чего нет НИГДЕ в мире), но и то, что название НАШИХ товаров НАШИ же экспортеры тщательно переводят на английский и иногда другие языки интересующих их рынков. Такое презрение к собственному языку, доходящее до двойных стандартов и нарушения международных правил перевода, свойственно только современным "русским".

Answer (score 3):

С языка оригинала можно перевести все, что переводится. Но это не означает, что все надо переводить поголовно. Названия марок , например, обычно не переводят. Ср.например, ваши примеры. Schwarzkopf. согласитесь, что для носителя русского перевод звучал комично, и вряд ли кто-н. воспринял бы всерьез наименования на русском. То же самое можно сказать ,например о Head@Shoulders ( Голова и плечи). К примеру, можете прочитать об этом: Названия брендов, компаний и товаров. Методы перевода.

Comment: Совершенно верно: нужно переводить всё, что переводится (в соответствии с международными правилами перевода), так и делается во всех других странах. Но только в России сейчас не переводится даже то, что можно и нужно. В русский язык усиленно внедряются американизмы. Задача - превратить русский язык, некогда язык величайшей мировой литературы и действующий рабочий язык ООН, в американский суржик. А затем поменять его название на рашенский.